# How to prevent Firefox for Android URL bar from appearing when dragging a div?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css, firefox

When you have a div in Firefox for Android, and it has a scrollbar, how can you prevent Firefox  from showing the URL bar while scrolling within the div?  It screws up my side navigation and makes the page very nauseating to use.

However, Google maps allows you to move the map around without the URL bar intruding into the screen.  It also allows you to move the map without hiding the URL bar if it's currently visible.  This tells me there some magical, simple trick to prevent that behavior.

Javascript and jQuery suggestions are welcome!

I have created a simple test page, located here:
http://www.boatlocal.com/mobiletest/testscroll.aspx

Here is the HTML of that entire page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent" />

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places,weather&sensor=true"></script> 
    <script src="/include/ui/jquery.ui.map.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/include/ui/jquery.ui.map.services.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <title>Test scroll</title>
    <style>
        .outerDiv{
            height: 1000px; 
            width: 100%;
            background: #c5d2d8; /* Old browsers */
            /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
            background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEgMSIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+CiAgPGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjAlIiB5MT0iMCUiIHgyPSIwJSIgeTI9IjEwMCUiPgogICAgPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iI2M1ZDJkOCIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjEwMCUiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiM2ZGIxY2UiIHN0b3Atb3BhY2l0eT0iMSIvPgogIDwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ+CiAgPHJlY3QgeD0iMCIgeT0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjEiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+);
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #c5d2d8 0%, #6db1ce 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#c5d2d8), color-stop(100%,#6db1ce)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #c5d2d8 0%,#6db1ce 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
            background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #c5d2d8 0%,#6db1ce 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
            background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #c5d2d8 0%,#6db1ce 100%); /* IE10+ */
            background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #c5d2d8 0%,#6db1ce 100%); /* W3C */
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#c5d2d8', endColorstr='#6db1ce',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */

        }
        .scrollDiv{
            height: 300px;
            width: 50%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            display: block;

            overflow-x: hidden;
            overflow-y: auto;
            background: white;
            border: solid 2px black;
        }

        .map{
            width: 80%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            height: 300px;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="outerDiv">
            <div class="scrollDiv">
                <ol>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                    <li>list item</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
            <div id="map_canvas" class="map rounded"></div>
    </div>



    </form>
</body>
     <script>
         var map;
         function initialize() {
             var mapOptions = {
                 zoom: 8,
                 center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
             };
             map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
                 mapOptions);
         }

         google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think you can prevent Firefox from showing the URL bar.  This is happening on the users phone you have no control over that.  Even more, this is most likely built into the Firefox .apk.

Comment: Then, how does Google prevent it?  I've added a map to my page so you can see what I mean.

Comment: Could it possibly be because your list is first?  Try putting the map above your list and see if it still happens.

Comment: Doesn't matter where the map is, the URL bar doesn't appear when you scroll around in it.

Comment: This is a simple example of a more complex page.  I have a div for the navigation menu on the left that slides out, and when the user tries to scroll within the menu, the URL bar keeps showing and hiding itself when you scroll up and down.  It's extremely annoying.

Comment: Try this, scroll down a bit, so that the scrollable div is still visible, but the page is scrolled down.  Then, scroll the div down a ways.  Then, try to scroll the div back toward the top (with the page scrolled down a bit).  The URL bar comes sliding into view after moving about 50 pixels.

Now try that same thing with the maps... scroll to the map and move it around.  No URL bar.